# Fill grid with two values on data-bind

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-grid

Okay so i got a grid that has two fields that i want to add the selected values from two dropdowns on but i am unable to get both of them to get added on the same value either i only get one value or it adds a line but shows no value

this is how the code looks while working with one attribute

```
<div id="gameSelectionForm">
<div class="col-sm-12 no-pad-sides">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label>@Resources.GetString("common.games"):</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-pad-sides">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select id="games" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: allGames, value: selectedGame"
                    data-text-field="Name" data-value-field="GameId" data-option-label="Select Games"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select id="rtp" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="source: allRtpLevels, value: selectedRtpLevel"
                    data-text-field="Level" data-value-field="RtpLevelId" data-option-label="Select RTP Level"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 no-pad-left">
            <button type="button" id="AddGameBtn" data-bind="click: addGame" class="blue-button k-primary k-button button-level-height max-width">
                <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>&nbsp;@Resources.GetString("common.add")
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="gamesGrid" data-role="grid"
             data-sortable="true"
             data-editable="{update: false, destroy: true, confirmation: false}"
             data-columns='[{"field": "Name", "title": "@Resources.GetString("common.name")"},{"field": "Level", "title": "@Resources.GetString("common.rtplevel")"},
                            {"command": "destroy", width: 150}] '
             data-bind="source: selectedGames"
             data-scrollable="true">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the logic

```
var gameSelectionViewModel = kendo.observable({
        allGames: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GamesList)),
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "GameId",
                    fields: {
                        GameId: { type: "number" },
                        Name: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        selectedRtpLevel: "",
        selectedGame: "",
        selectedGames: '@(Model.SelectedGames != null)' === 'True' ? @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.SelectedGames)) : new kendo.data.DataSource(),
        selectedRtpLevels: '@(Model.SelectedRtpLevel != null)' === 'True' ? @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.SelectedRtpLevel)) : new kendo.data.DataSource(),
        addGame: function () {
            if (gameSelectionViewModel.selectedGame === '' || gameSelectionViewModel.selectedRtpLevel === '')
                return;

            var selectedRtpLevel = gameSelectionViewModel.allRtpLevels.get(gameSelectionViewModel.selectedRtpLevel);
            var selectedRtpLevels = gameSelectionViewModel.selectedRtpLevels.data();
            var selectedGames = gameSelectionViewModel.selectedGames.data();
            var selectedGame = gameSelectionViewModel.allGames.get(gameSelectionViewModel.selectedGame);

            if (selectedGame && selectedGames.indexOf(selectedGame) < 0) {
                selectedGames.push(selectedGame)
            } else {
                warnBox('Game already exists!');
            }
        },
        allRtpLevels: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.RtpConfigurations)),
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "RtpLevelId",
                    fields: {
                        RtpLevelId: { type: "number" },
                        Level: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });

    // Attach view model to html
    kendo.bind($("#gameSelectionForm"), gameSelectionViewModel);
```

and the line were it adds is

```
if (selectedGame && selectedGames.indexOf(selectedGame) < 0) {
            selectedGames.push(selectedGame)
```

I have been trying all sort of solution with two pushes but that gives values on different rows. i am new to using kendo and haven't quite wrapped my head around how to use it. How can i ge both the selectedRtpLevel and selectedGame to appear in the grid when i call the addGame function?

Comment: is this what you are expecting to happen? http://dojo.telerik.com/oJofAgoD

Comment: @DavidShorthose Yeah thats exactly what i wanted! if you write a answer i accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dojo I prepared.

http://dojo.telerik.com/oJofAgoD

The main takeaway here is how you are trying to compare and add the game to your datasource.

I have simplified the process somewhat by replacing your `addGame` function with the following code:

```
if (gameSelectionViewModel.selectedGame === '' || gameSelectionViewModel.selectedRtpLevel === '')
                return;


          var newgame = {Name:gameSelectionViewModel.get("selectedGame"), Level:gameSelectionViewModel.get("selectedRtpLevel")}; 

          var filteredList = gameSelectionViewModel.get("selectedGames").data().filter(function(item){
            return item.Level === newgame.Level &&  item.Name === newgame.Name;
          }); 

          console.log(filteredList); 

          if(newgame && (filteredList === undefined || filteredList.length === 0))
          {
             gameSelectionViewModel.selectedGames.add(newgame); 
          }
          else 
          {
            alert('game already added'); 
          }
```

the big thing here is you are constructing the object that sits in the datasource not what is being displayed in the grid. so I usually like to have a function that gets me a default object or allows me to construct an object that can slot into the datasource with the correct properties set.

then to determine if the newly constructed game is in the collection I am just filtering through and we expect to see the filtered list to be either undefined or have a zero length. anything other than that and we know we have that item already in the collection so don't add it.